# Django admin page - open 'VIEW SITE' in a new tab?

Tags: django

In admin portal of my Django app (v. 3.1), is it possible to configure the "VIEW SITE" link in the site header so that it will open in a new tab, `target="blank"`? I'm referring here to the link whose `href` can be configured via `admin.site.site_url`... I'd like to give my admin users quick and easy access to the site linked there, but I don't want them to be navigating away from their authenticated admin session.

I currently have this value set to a custom configuration in urls.py like so

```
protocol = 'https'
domain = 'mysite.com'

if os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT'):
    protocol = 'http'
    domain = 'localhost:8080'

admin.site.site_url = f'{protocol}://{domain}'
```

as this URL actually needs to point at an application running on a different server.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, search in the codebase for `site_url` or `View site` values.
If you found it then update it:

```
<a href="{{ site_url }}" target="_blank">{% trans 'View site' %}</a>
```

If it doesn't exist, then make a copy of the django source code’s `base.html` template: `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html` and paste it into your new custom template: `PROJECT_DIRECTORY/template/admin/base_site.html`. Then update it by adding the `_blank` attribute that is shown above.

Comment: Thank you - I copied Django's base.html into my own base_site.html and made the adjustment, worked perfectly.